# Number theorems with chapter number

Tags: numbering, environments, amsthm, thmtools

I use `declaretheoremstyle` to define a theorem environment, and print a list of theorems in the end of my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
  headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
  postheadspace=1em,
  notefont=\bfseries,
  notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\itshape,
  shaded={bgcolor=yellow!20}
]{thmstyle}

\declaretheorem[style=thmstyle,name=Theorem]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Somebody]
...
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
...
\end{theorem}

\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Theorems}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtheoremname}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show=theorem]

\end{document}
```

The theorems are numbered from the beginning to the end of the book, and from `1`:

[image]

However, I would like to number the theorems with chapter number (like Figures or Tables), for instance, `1.1` (the first theorem in Chapter 1), `1.2` (the first theorem in Chapter 2)...

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add

```
numberwithin=chapter
```

to the definition:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
  headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
  postheadspace=1em,
  notefont=\bfseries,
  notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\itshape,
  shaded={bgcolor=yellow!20}
]{thmstyle}

\declaretheorem[style=thmstyle,name=Theorem,numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}
\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Theorems}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter one}
\begin{theorem}[Somebody]
test
\end{theorem}

\chapter{Test chapter two}
\begin{theorem}
test
\end{theorem}

    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtheoremname}
    \listoftheorems[ignoreall,show=theorem]

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting List of Theorems:

[image]